# image view getWidth() and getHeight() return 0 for kyocera phone

Tags: android, android-imageview

iam working on a project and i need the height an width for an image view , i am simply calling the `getwidth()` and `getheight()` normally like this

```
int targetW = mImageView.getWidth() ;
int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();
```

its working fine for all kind of android phones but when i am trying a kyocera hydro phone its return zero !
i am calling it after the image view rendered to the screen for sure because i am calling them when clicking on the view itself.

any suggestions ?

EDITED:
**Its working fine for all phones except for Kyocera Hydro phone**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), mImageView.getWidth() + "", Toast.DURATION_SHORT).show();

                    // remove OnGlobalLayoutListener, check Android version too
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        mImageView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    else
                        mImageView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
```

Comment: can you explain why ? i t must work on all api versions

Comment: well, as far as I know, there are some points need to point out:

1: OnGlobalLayoutListener will actives its onGlobalLayout() method as soon as your whole view is built (please check Document for more information). So at that point of time, you will have the value of your View (instead of -1 or -2 in case of MATCH_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT).

2: OnGlobalLayoutListener has been updated (GlobalOnLayoutListener to OnGlobalLayoutListener)  in versions so you have to check the version when use.

Is this answer Ok for you?

Comment: I don't have a property answer for you. But when I work with some Sony and Samsung devices, I think what they did with the Android OS changed the things and caused some strange behaviours comparing to others. So don't be panic, it's just because your device's OS has been modified.